# Python - Int object is not callable error when I call an instance?

Tags: python

I get a int object is not callable error when I try and create an instance of the class. From looking at similar questions, it might be due to naming? I'm not sure.

```
    class Employee:
    """Class to represent employee"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary):
       """Initialize employee."""
       self.fn = first_name
       self.ln = last_name
       self.salary = salary

    def give_raise(salary, amount=5000):
       """Raise salary by default amount unless other amount is specified."""
       self.salary += amount


    Employee_1 = Employee('john', 'doe', 50_000)

    Employee_1.salary()
```

Comment: remove `()`... it's `Employee_1.salary`

Comment: `Employee_1.salary` is an integer, and `Employee_1.salary()` attempts to call this integer, which doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: salary is a class attribute, not a function. Just do Employee_1.salary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Employee_1.salary` instead of `Employee_1.salary()`.

Comment: `50_000` is a valid integer.

Comment: @RonieMartinez Yes got it. After  Python 3.6